# Question about Hubble parameter (Hubble constant) and measuring it

Tags: observational-astronomy, cosmology, redshift, hubble-constant, doppler-effect

I see this question in "An introduction to modern cosmology - Andrew Liddle - Wiley Publication":

> In the real Universe the expansion is not completely uniform. Rather,
> galaxies exhibit some random motion relative to the overall Hubble
> expansion, known as their pecuLiar veLocity and caused by the
> gravitational pull of their near neighbours. Supposing that a typical
> (eg root mean square) galaxy peculiar velocity is 600 km/s, how far
> away would a galaxy have to be before it could be used to determine
> the Hubble constant to ten per cent accuracy, supposing
>
> (a) The true
> value of the Hubble constant is 100 km/s Mpc?
>
> (b) The true value
> of the Hubble constant is 50 km/sMpc ?
>
> Assume in your
> calculation that the galaxy distance and red-shift could be measured
> exactly. Unfortunately, that is not true of real observations.

I really don't know how to start solving this. What do we need to find Hubble constant. I know $v=H.r$ but I don't know how to calculate the effect of peculiar velocity. we don't know $v$ and $r$ in Hubble formula, how to find $H$?

Answer (score 2):

You can start by working out how fast a galaxy must be receding if its peculiar velocity (given as about 600 km/s) is less than or equal to 10% of its expansion velocity.

I'm not going to spell out the next step as you said you don't know where to start.